# How to parse website text and displaying in a view

Tags: ios, xcode, view, xml-parsing

I'd like to load a web page and parse the article text and title only, then display this in a view. Is it possible to do this without using UIWebVIew? If its possible, I'd prefer to use only built in functions and no plugins.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a HTTP reqest to get the html content string, then parse the string.
For example, to get the title of html:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
if(html) {
    NSLog(@"HTML %@", html);

    NSRange r = [html rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange r1 = [html rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
        if (r1.location != NSNotFound) {
            if (r1.location > r.location) {
                NSString *title = [html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(r), r1.location - NSMaxRange(r))];
                NSLog(@"title %@", title);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to parse a webpage, and get what is relevant as an "article", and its title, without all the other stuff, you need something like [Diffbot](http://www.diffbot.com/) to retrieve article title, author, text, and content-relative image(s). Diffbot is paid for applications which make more than 10.000 API calls a month (which is not much). Applications like [Readability](http://www.readability.com/), Pocket (formerly Read It Later) and Instapaper, which allow their users to save parsed articles for later reading across multiple devices, have public APIs. Pocket does not allow its API to be used only for parsing, though; Readability supposedly provides access to its parser ("Content API") upon request (I haven't made that request, though I might need to in future); and Instapaper, which, unlike the other two, I have never used as an application, doesn't really make it clear whether it allows this kind of use.

I hope my answer, though many months late, can still be useful; please reply briefly what solution you have found (if you have).

P.S.: Apparently, as a new user I am only allowed to give you two links; I have removed all the subsequent ones, but the first two are the most useful anyway.

Comment: Your links are to things that the OP specifically mentioned he was not interested in.